# undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass while the object exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a blog using ruby on rails and while I'm coding the comments views and I got strange error, which I could not find a solution for

I'm tring to read user name from comment.user and it return this erorr

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

If I did inspect the user object, I see the data inside

```
<%= comment.user.inspect %>
```

I added the associations between the models correctly

User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy


end
```

Post model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment model

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

comment View

```
<strong><%= comment.user.name %>:</strong><%= comment.body %><br><br>
```

Any help please?

Edit 2:

Comments controller code

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /comments
  # GET /comments.json
  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
  end

  # GET /comments/1
  # GET /comments/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /comments/new
  def new
    @post = Post.find params[:post_id]
  end

  # GET /comments/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /comments
  # POST /comments.json
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @post = Post.find params[:post_id]
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id 
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1
  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update(comment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /comments/1
  # DELETE /comments/1.json
  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to comments_url, notice: 'Comment was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :user_id, :post_id)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try?

```
<%= comment.user.name if comment.user %>
```

Comment: Try in the console to find if  there's any :) `Comment.where(user: nil)`

Comment: it return empty #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

Comment: but I notice that the partial view loop 4 times while I have 3 comments in a post

Comment: @FDI edit your question and add the code responsible for the action in controller.

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej, Please check it, I added it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this `<%= comment.user.try(:name) %>`.

It's possible that some comment doesn't contain user value.

Comment: it works too, I checked all comments from the console and all comments have a user_id, why does it happen, can you please explain?

Comment: Please check, surely some user_id is not available in User model it self.

Comment: Prefer Ruby's safe navigation over try, `comment.user&.name`.

Answer (score 0):

`try` method is defined on Object class and NilClass class in Rails and it's not part of Ruby itself. You can use `try` when you are dealing with potential nil objects.

`<%= comment.user.try(:name) %>.`

When you use `try` in your case, NoMethodError exception will not be raised and nil will be returned instead of the receiving object is a nil object or NilClass.

For more info, you can look up this [link](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/NilClass.html#method-i-try)